# Ajax request in es6 vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, ecmascript-6

I am able to make an ajax request using jquery and es5 but I want to transition me code so that its vanilla and uses es6. How would this request change. (Note: I am querying Wikipedia's api).

```
      var link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&pageids="+ page +"&format=json&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: link,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(re){
    },
      error:function(u){
        console.log("u")
        alert("sorry, there are no results for your search")
    }
```

Comment: You would use the fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: XMLHttpRequest .... or fetch ... you decide ... by the way, this really has nothing to do with ES5 vs ES6

Comment: Either would be fine. But I would prefer fetch.

Comment: You are making a JSONP request which is a script request and not supported by `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` as others have suggested

Comment: `Either would be fine. But I would prefer fetch` - then do so

Comment: @charlietfl - you scrolled right :p didn't see the JSONP palaver on that link :p

Comment: Doesn't look like a JSONP request is necessary for the wikipedia API. Just a simple JSON request will do.

Comment: @Andy - trouble is, wikipedia does not issue CORS headers, so it would be necessary to use JSONP - and in that case, neither XMLHttpRequest nor fetch is an option

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Probably, you will use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
fetch(link, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }})
    .then(res => res.json()) // parse response as JSON (can be res.text() for plain response)
    .then(response => {
        // here you do what you want with response
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("u")
        alert("sorry, there are no results for your search")
    });
```

If you want to make *not async*, it is impossible. But you can make it look like not async operation with [Async-Await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) feature.

Comment: If fetch already returns a promise, what could you mean by 'make async, it is impossible'? Seems like you can't avoid it!

Comment: Thank you, changed it to "not async".

Answer (score 2):

AJAX requests are useful to send data asynchronously, get response, check it and apply to current web-page via updating its content.

```
function ajaxRequest()
{
    var link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&pageids="+ page +"&format=json&callback=?";
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // creates 'ajax' object
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() //monitors and waits for response from the server
        {
           if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) //checks if response was with status -> "OK"
           {
               var re = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText); //gets data and parses it, in this case we know that data type is JSON. 
               if(re["Status"] === "Success")
               {//doSomething}
               else 
               {
                   //doSomething
               }
           }

        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", link); //set method and address
        xmlHttp.send(); //send data

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you don't need to use jQuery or any API. It's as simple as doing this:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'https://www.example.com');
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Are you kidding me?  That is the oldest way of doing it, which was the whole reason jQuery was invented (to get around such tedious APIs). In modern JS, "nowadays", you should use the `fetch()` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch