# Replace jQuery with vanilla JS when parsing JSON, and other improvements

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I would like get rid of jQuery for this simple task, but I don't know how to use vanilla JS to do the job. The page works fine, but I recognize that it is a mess, and I would like to improve the invisible, under the hood code.

I am a complete noob, I will try to explain what I've done but I need your help to simplify as much as possible and clean the code (one function only / alternative to javascript in "href" / everything else that comes to mind). And to get rid of a 88kB .js file just to call a function.

The web page contains two links that point to local Icecast streams.
When one selects a stream by clicking a link,

- the common audio player loads the corresponing source URL (function `changeStream()`);
- the link is highligted and every other link returns to the default CSS (function `changeBg()`);
- the variable `number` is set to the correspondibg element number to allow title parsing;
- the jQuery function `getTitle()` is executed.

Additional notes:

- HTML IDs with "*-js" means that they are modified by a javascript function;
- I may have mispelled something below, I have rewritten variables and other parts with easier to understand names;
- Getting rid of jQuery is my priority, but other improvements are well accepted.

Thank you in advance

---

The webpage contains is

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>[...]</head>
<body>
<div class="links">
  <a id="/sourceA-js" class="sourceLink"
     href="javascript:changeStream('/radio/sourceA'); changeBg('/sourceA-js'); var number=0; getTitle();">
    <span class="sourceText">Stream A</span></a>
  <a id="/sourceB-js" class="sourceLink"
     href="javascript:changeStream('/radio/sourceB'); changeBg('/sourceB-js'); var number=1; getTitle();">
    <span class="sourceText">Stream B</span></a>
</div>
<div id="currentTrackInfo">
  <p>Track: <span id="currentTrackTitle-js">Please select a radio stream</span>
  </p>
  <audio id="radio-js" class="radioPlayer" controls>
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</div>

<script>
  function changeBg (streamId) {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('sourceLink'),
      i = boxes.length;
    while (i--) {
      boxes[i].removeAttribute('style');
    }
    document.getElementById(streamid).setAttribute('style', 'color:grey;background-color:red;');
  }

  function changeStream (stream) {
    document.getElementById('radio-js').pause();
    document.getElementById('radio-js').setAttribute('src', stream);
    document.getElementById('radio-js').load();
    document.getElementById('radio-js').play();
  }
</script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function getTitle () {
    jQuery.get('status-json.xsl', {}, function (response) {
      $('#currentTrackTitle-js').html(response.icestats.source[number]['title']);
      document.title = response.icestats.source[number]['title'];
    });
  }

  gettitle();
  setInterval(gettitle, 15000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

The parsed file, `status-json.xsl`, contains

```js
{
  "icestats": {
    "admin": "mail",
    "host": "domain",
    "location": "name",
    "server_id": "version",
    "server_start": "humandate",
    "server_start_iso8601": "computerdate",
    "source": [
      {
        "audio_info": "bitrate=320",
        "bitrate": 320,
        "genre": "Jazz",
        "listener_peak": 2,
        "listeners": 1,
        "listenurl": "address",
        "server_description": "streamdescription",
        "server_name": "streamname",
        "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
        "server_url": "/radio/jazz",
        "stream_start": "humandate",
        "stream_start_iso8601": "computerdate",
        "title": "author - title",
        "dummy": null
      },
      {
        "audio_info": "bitrate=320",
        "bitrate": 320,
        "genre": "Jazz",
        "listener_peak": 2,
        "listeners": 1,
        "listenurl": "address",
        "server_description": "streamdescription",
        "server_name": "streamname",
        "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
        "server_url": "/radio/jazz",
        "stream_start": "humandate",
        "stream_start_iso8601": "computerdate",
        "title": "author - title",
        "dummy": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax request in es6 vanilla javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906665/ajax-request-in-es6-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: Use `fetch("status-json.xsl").then(r => r.json()).then(function (response) { ... });` and `document.querySelector('#currentTrackTitle-js').textContent = response....;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the only jQuery code that you want to replace:

```js
jQuery.get("status-json.xsl", {}, function(response) {
  $('#currentTrackTitle-js').html(response.icestats.source[number]['title']);
  document.title = response.icestats.source[number]['title'];
});
```

Vanilla JavaScript equivalent to `jQuery.get()` is [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). This will read JSON string from file and convert it to a JavaScript object:

```js
fetch("status-json.xsl")
  .then(response => {
    // parse JSON from 'status-json.xsl' file
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(status => {
    // perform your app logic here
  });
```

This jQuery code:

```js
$('#currentTrackTitle-js').html(response.icestats.source[number]['title']);
```

can be replaced with this vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const currTitle = document.getElementById('currentTrackTitle-js');
currTitle.innerHTML = status[number]['title'];
```

Putting it all together:

```js
const currTitle = document.getElementById('currentTrackTitle-js');

fetch("status-json.xsl")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(status => {
    currTitle.innerHTML = status.icestats.source[number]['title'];
    document.title = status.icestats.source[number]['title'];
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting `TypeError: resJSON.icestats is undefined` if I replace the `// handle` with the `const` block. The .xsl is correctly reached with a status code of 200

Comment: Unfortunately now I'm getting `TypeError: status.icestats is undefined`

Comment: Thank you, it works now. Any other suggestion to improve the reamining javascript in the page? For example removing it from the href, or running getTitle() only if "number" is defined

Comment: @Polizi8 It looks like `getTitle()` displays the title of the song being played. You're calling `getTitle()` every 15 seconds. Wouldn't it be better to call it whenever the audio input changes?

Comment: I need it to retrieve the track title if it changes. I did further improvements: now getTitle checks if number is undefined before launching the fetch function and I removed the inline js using addEventListener