# Is there any ES6 equivalent for ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

in vanillaJS we are doing something like that to ajax call :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','file.json',true);
request.onload = function (){
if(this.status >= 200 && this.status<400){
 var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
 console.log(data);
}
else{console.log("Error !");
}
request.send();
```

Now if we do this with arrow Functions it won't work because of `this` keyword.

Is there anyway to solve this problem and use it with arrow function or should I just stick with old way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax request in es6 vanilla javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906665/ajax-request-in-es6-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz that was using Jquery I'm doing this with plain JS

Comment: @IhateReact did you see any of the answers?

Comment: @VLAZ i saw fetch api but i wonder if there's a way with xmlhttpRequest

Comment: @IhateReact I don't think that is what your question says. You asked for an ES6 equivalent. `fetch()` is that. Well, it's not *exactly* ES6 (not part of the ES spec but browser one) but it came out at that time anyway. It's very much linked to ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, there is no an "ES6 equivalent" for `XMLHttpRequest` (not even `fetch`) simply because none of them is an ECMAScript feature but part of the Web platform API defined by WHATWG and W3C.

However, to rewrite your code in a more "modern" way, using some ES6 features, you can procede as follows:

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
  // YOU COULD ALSO ACCESS request AS e.target HERE.  

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    const data = JSON.parse(request.response);
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    console.log('ERROR');
  }
});

request.open('GET', 'file.json');
request.send();
```

Essentially we are using `addEventListener` API (which is still not an ES feature, but the latest specification to handle events in browsers). Then we are using `const` and an arrow function as handler which are ES6 features.

You don't need to use `this` as you can access your request through the `event` object or leveraging the reference stored in `request` variable.